# Working around gem dependency issues when upgrading to Rails 6.beta

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, active-model-serializers, ruby-on-rails-6

Trying to play around with Rails 6 beta in existing app. Updated Gemfile to include `gem 'rails', '6.0.0.beta3'`

Unfortunately some gems, like *active_model_serializers* depend on a version "< 6" and don't have a beta in testing that I can find.

Any workarounds other than forking and making my own version?

```
$ bundle update

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    active_model_serializers (~> 0.10.7) was resolved to 0.10.9, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 4.1, < 6)

    clearance (= 1.17.0) was resolved to 1.17.0, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 3.1)

    clearance (= 1.17.0) was resolved to 1.17.0, which depends on
      email_validator (~> 1.4) was resolved to 1.6.0, which depends on
        activemodel

    rails (~> 6.0.0.beta3) was resolved to 6.0.0.beta3, which depends on
      activemodel (= 6.0.0.beta3)

    simple_form (~> 4.1) was resolved to 4.1.0, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
```

Comment: alternative to offending gems :)?

Comment: but wait, because am learning, I also had some play with gem 'rails', '6.0.0.beta3' in an existing app and I managed to get bundle install through by first comment all gems and did bundle install first with gem 'rails', '6.0.0.beta3' only, then uncomment gems one after one running bundle update and it worked. Coffee-rails was difficult so I removed version and it worked.  I this process on 2  applications. Not sure this is an answer to your question but I would like to know, just curious :)

Comment: Looks like they are tracking the [issue for ActiveModel Serializers here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/2320). You might try forking it yourself and trying it out with a looser constraint, or replacing it with something like JBuilder or `as_json` (may not be reasonable for a large app).

Comment: I also did as @olucube.com Commented offending gems, ran `bundle update rails` and then uncommented them and ran `bundle install`. Found no other way.